# Как прекратить работу приложения прекращая все воркеры и сервисы?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня появилась идея добавлять в приложение дистанционный блокер, чтобы в случае не уплаты клиентом за работу, можно было заблокировать приложение.
 Логику я придумал, а вот к самому эффективному методу блокирования ещё не пришёл. 
Пока что не придумал ничего лучше чем “ finishAndRemoveTask() “, что будет просто не давать возможность открыть приложение. 
Просто интерестно, может есть какие то идеи как ещё можно прекратить работу приложения не просто закрывая его например, а ещё и прекращая все воркеры и сервисы?

Answer (score 0):

Для api>=16  - `finishAffinity()`

Для api>=21 - `finishAndRemoveTask()` - ваш способ.

Так же есть вариант такой:

```
this.finish();
Process.killProcess( Process.myPid() );
```

Закрыть приложение можно и таким способом:

```
this.finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Убить процессы можно так:

```
Process.sendSignal(pid, Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
```

Чтобы полностью все убить можно использовать такой способ:

```
ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageNameToKill)
```

Но предварительно проверьте в манифесте разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

Comment: Эти три метода не импотрируются
            Process.killProcess( Process.myPid() )
Process.sendSignal(0, Process.SIGNAL_KILL)
  ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.example.packageNameToKill")

точнее, import android.os.Process.* автоматически импортируются 
но горит серым, соответственно сами методы красным

killBackgroundProcesses не имортируется совсем. 
Остальные варианты не отвечают на вопрос.